# Rendering Problem on Samsung Devices with Android 14 and One UI 6

Tags: java, android-studio, samsung-galaxy

I am puzzled. I have done this layout in Android Studio. It is rendering fine on all devices except Samsung with Android 14 and One UI 6. Can you spot any problems in this XML causing the Text View to disappear on Samsung Devices?

I have verified the XML on Sony Xperia 1 family mobiles and on Pixel 7 Pro Devices.

```html
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="430dp"
        android:layout_height="253dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_portrait"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/circularImageView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/stradislogo"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/semiTransparentWhite"
        app:civ_border_width="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="168dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="Anfahrt"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="159dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="168dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="Plasmaspende-Zentrum in Egelsbach"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="351dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/routenplanung"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="Routenplanung"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:cornerRadius="20dp" />

            <!-- Map View -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:text="@string/stradis_med_gmbh_anfahrt" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />


        </LinearLayout>




    </ScrollView>




</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you have to assign a font colour to the text in the text view. If the device is in dark mode, the text won’t be shown.